# Laravel ajax progressbar

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have script below and i'm trying to get percentage of upload progress but nothing shows till my file uploaded fully!

## Code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nationBtn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('national', $('#national')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
      },
      UploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        $('.progress-bar').text(percentComplete + '%');
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
      },
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: fd,
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,

      success: function(data) {
        if (data.error) {
          $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
          $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
        }

        if (data.success) {
          $('.progress-bar').text('Uploaded successfully.');
          $('.progress-bar').css('width', '100%');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="{{route('nationalUpload')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      @csrf @method('POST')

      <input type="file" name="national" id="national" class="form-control">
      <div class="progress mt-2">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
          0%
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="mt-3 nationBtn btn btn-primary">Upload</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Issue

I do not get any percentage in my progress bar.

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

There is issue that your csrf token is not passed along with header so i have made some changes in your script please see below code,
You do not need to append each field individually entire form can be passed with new FormData(this) when on('submit') event is triggered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=""csrf-token""]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var fd = new FormData(this);
    /* fd.append('national', $('#national')[0].files[0]);
    fd.append('_token',$(document).find('input[name=""_token""]').val()) */

    $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
      },
      UploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        $('.progress-bar').text(percentComplete + '%');
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
      },
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: fd,
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,

      success: function(data) {
        if (data.error) {
          $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
          $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
        }

        if (data.success) {
          $('.progress-bar').text('Uploaded successfully.');
          $('.progress-bar').css('width', '100%');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
  </script>
```